# Unable to update to latest version of R

Tags: r, cran

I am trying to update to R version 3.5.3, by using the R manual. However, when I type this line:

deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu cosmic-cran35/

I get a return of command not found.

I tried to add it to my source list as previously suggested, but this does not seem to work. I am trying to do this on a linux system

Comment: deb is not  a command, check out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233064/why-am-i-getting-command-deb-not-found/233069)

Comment: also for installing R on ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031597/r-3-5-0-for-ubuntu)

Comment: The second post about installing is now out of date

Comment: Just _read_ the appropriate [README](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) at the source repository and its mirror -- it has all instructions and detail!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel the README is a great resource but it does skip over *how* to add the appropriate `deb` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` which is seemingly what the OP was struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Thanks @Ralf for correction (see comments)

Append the '`deb`' line to your `sources.list` by opening a terminal and typing:

```
echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu cosmic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Install the R-CRAN GPG key to verify what you're installing:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Update your package list and install with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev
```

Comment: In order to append something to a file you have write access only through `sudo` you need the pattern `echo <whatever> | sudo tee -a <file>`.

Comment: It unfortunately returns with 'permission denied', when I try to append the 'deb' line

Comment: @RalfStubner I always forget that. Thanks, fixed

Comment: I forgot you need to use `tee` with files with root permissions, as @RalfStubner pointed out. Corrected the answer